# How can I speed up downloading files using paramiko?

Tags: sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I have written code for downloading file from SFTP server but the process is taking a lot of time. Could you please tell me is there any way to speed up the process?

Code I am using -

```
import paramiko

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname='****',port=22,username='*****',password='', key_filename='******')
sftp_obj= ssh_client.open_sftp()
sftp_obj.get(sftp_loc, ec2_loc)
```